# Missing key even when exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, struct

I'm using the following code to create a presigned url:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
)

func main() {
    configuration := s3.PutObjectInput{ Key: aws.String("default_key") }

    // Add Bucket to configuration from environment variable
    // e.g:
    //    CONFIGURATION_BUCKET -> configuration.Bucket
    err := envconfig.Process("configuration", &configuration)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
      SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    }))
    svc := s3.New(sess)
    req, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&configuration)

    url, err := req.Presign(15 * time.Minute)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("Url is", url)
}
```

The key is always the same, but the bucket can change depending on the environment that I'm.

When I print with `fmt.Println` the Bucket and Key exists:

```
fmt.Println(configuration.Bucket, configuration.Key) // returns address
```

But the following error happens: `required key CONFIGURATION_KEY missing value`

Thank you!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Ops... I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the type [`s3.PutObjectInput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#PutObjectInput), the `key` field has a `required:"true"` tag.

The `required` tag is also used by the `envconfig` package to indicate that the environment variable is required.

You either need to supply the key from the environment, or not use the aws structs directly with the `envconfig` package.

Comment: Hm. What about mixing them together? Isn't that possible?

Comment: @FXux: what do you mean by "mixing them together"?

Comment: I'm learning Go, and I have mainly a background in JavaScript. So I'm used to use objects, and they are very flexible, you can combine two or more into one. Is that something doable with structs?

Comment: @FXux: You cannot change the structure of the types at runtime.